# how to trigger a function in vuejs after the page is loaded?

Tags: function, vue.js, hook, call

I am trying to trigger a function which hides or show the images on the basis of data i have written two function one which calls the api which is in created hook and second function which renders the image . The problem is how do i call that second function after the dom is loaded , right now when i am trying to call in the first function or created it is returning me error that css cannot be changed of null.I have tried using mounted function with newtick but its still firing the render_badges function first and hence values are null inside

created:function(){
      this.loadlike()

```
},

methods:{
      loadlike:function(){
        var self = this
        this.$http.get('/api/user_profile').then(function (res) {
          self.tasksdata = res.body
          self.badges = self.tasksdata.data2
          console.log(self.badges)
          console.log(this.tasksdata)
          console.log(this.max)

        })
      },


      getHumanDate : function (date) {

                return moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss').locale("en-gb").format('LL');

            },


            render_badges:function(){
                var self = this
                var counter = 0;
                self.badges.map(function(e){
                    counter ++;
                    console.log(counter)
                    if(counter <=self.max){
                       document.getElementById("i").style.display = "initial";
                    }
                    else{
                      document.getElementById("i").style.display = "none";

                    }
                })

            },

mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.render_badges();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manipulating the DOM, you should use v-if on the element itself that turns it on or off based on data. It is a different way of thinking than direct DOM manipulation learned in the jQuery days. Read more in the Vue docs about [conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html).

If you are wanting to trigger once the DOM is available, use mounted()

Comment: hey will surely look into conditional rendering but i wanted to do via mounted and i tried         mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.render_badges();
  })
}  but somehow the data in that function is coming null which was fetched in created

Comment: Oh I see. You have to declare that data in data() first, otherwise its not going to do anything with it. Something like:

data(){ return{
badges: []}

Comment: Yes it's declared taskdata,badges and Max but still getting null in render badges , loadlike function is working fine

Comment: Its hard to see without the full javascript from the component. Is there a reason you're using map instead of forEach?